# Reset iteration index after using next() Python

Tags: python, file, iteration

I am trying to edit a text file using `fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1)`
The text file has say 5 lines:

```
line 0
line 1
line 2 
line 3
line 4
```

I wish to change data of `line 1` based on info in `line 2`.
So I use a `for` loop

```
infile = fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1)
for line in infile:
 if(line2Data):
   #do something on line1
   print line,
 else:
   line1=next(infile)
   line2=next(infile) 
   #do something with line2
```

Now my problem is after the 1st iteration the `line` is set to `line2` so in 2nd iteration the line is set to `line3`. I want line to be set to `line1` in 2nd iteration. I have tried `line = line` but it doesn't work.
Can you please let me know how I am reset the iteration index on `line` which gets changed due to `next`

PS: This is a simple example of a huge file and function I am working on.

Comment: Why don't you just store the first line and then use it later?

Comment: Because the file has to be printed serially

Comment: How do you know that you want to start again ? Do you want to start again always from the beginning ?

Comment: Yes i want to start again from beginning or from the next index i.e. 1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (and that is not much) there is no way in resetting an iterator. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266180/can-iterators-be-reset-in-python) is maybe useful. Since you say the file is huge, what I can think of is to process only part of the data. Following nosklos answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python), I would try something like this (but that is really just a first guess):

```
while True:
    for line in open('really_big_file.dat')
        process_data(line)
        if some_condition==True:
            break
```

Ok, your answer that you might want to start from the previous index is not captured with this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reset the iterator, but there is nothing stopping your from doing some of your processing before you start your loop:

```
infile = fileinput.input("foo.txt")

first_lines = [next(infile) for x in range(3)]
first_lines[1] = first_lines[1].strip() + " this is line2 > " + first_lines[2]
print "\n".join(first_lines)

for line in infile:
    print line
```

This uses `next()` to read the first 3 lines into a list. It then updates `line1` based on `line2` and prints all of them. It then continues to print the rest of the file using a normal loop.

For your sample, the output would be:

```
line 0

line 1 this is line2 > line 2 

line 2 

line 3

line 4
```

Note, if your are trying to modify the first lines of the file itself, rather than just display it, you would need to write the whole file to a new file. Writing to a file does not work like in a Word processor where all the lines move down when a line or character is added. It works as if you were in `overwrite` mode.