# String Index Out Of Range When Reading Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep on getting this error on the second last line of my program , and I am not sure why , all I am doing is reading a line from a text file.

```
if (items[0]) == 86947367 :
        with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
            try:
                price = int(text_file.readlines()[2])
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else:
                new_price = int(price * (items2[0]))
                print("£",new_price)
                price_list.append(new_price)
                product = (text_file.readline()[1])
                print(product)
```

Comment: there is nothing more for the `readline()` to read since the `readlines()` read them all.

Comment: so can i read another line ? without the last 2 lines , my codes works great. ( this is only a chunk of my program)

Comment: No. you either read them all at once and store that somewhere to process it **or** you read it line by line and process the data as it comes

Comment: yes I am trying to read line by line , the only way I know how to do this is .readline(). I want my code to print out the price then the product in that order.

Comment: then why are you using `readlines()` with an 's' at the end?

Comment: but if I use .readline()[3] for example it print the 3rd letter not word. So the from the word banana , it will print n.

Comment: every instance of `readline()` is a string and as such it does exactly what you describe when indexed. to get the third line you have to execute `readline()` three times; once for every line. Normally, we don't do that. though. We try to look for patterns in a file. Btw `'banana'[3]` returns `'a'`. Python is 0-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `readlines()`, your "cursor" in the file reaches the end. If you call it a second time, it'll have nothing left to read.

To avoid this behavior, you can store `readlines()` in a variable for multiple uses, or use `text_file.seek(0)` to put your cursor back at the beginning of the file.

Comment: yes  .seek() worked great thank you. so does this function just reset the "cursor" ?

Comment: @Mikel.JKK : .seek() just moves the cursor in your iterator at a certain position. If you need a more detailed answer, you can check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266180/can-iterators-be-reset-in-python

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

```
price = int(text_file.readlines()[2])
```

the readlines() cause the readline() to return none or something like that.
try to store readlines() in a 
**tmp var and then**

```
price = tmp[2]
product =tmp[1]
```