# Why does this code (Python) only return one line?

Tags: python, file

I recently started programming and I wanted to sort a file, but in the end, this code only returns one line, even though the text file has 65 lines...

```
f = open(".\\test.txt")
g, u = [], []
a = 0


for i, line in enumerate(f):
    a += 1
    if i%2 == 0:
        g.append(f.readlines()[i])
        print(i),
    elif i%2 == 1:
        u.append(f.readlines()[i])
        print(i),


print(u),
print(g)
```

Comment: You can't use `readlines()` like you did. Have a look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226586/string-index-out-of-range-when-reading-text-file/39227745#39227745)

Comment: Surely you can replace `append(f.readlines()[i])` with `append(line)`...

Comment: @RandomDavis that works perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop starts reading the file line by line. But then its contents go and read the rest of the file in a single `readlines` call; after that, there's nothing more to be read! So you end up with the first line in `line` and the second line in `g`, since you only kept one of the lines that `readlines()` read.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
lines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    a += 1
    if i%2 == 0:
        g.append(lines[i])
        print(i),
    elif i%2 == 1:
        u.append(lines[i])
        print(i),
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a value error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: sorry, typo. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

`open(filename)` gives you an iterator over the lines of a file. This iterator will be exhausted after reading all the lines *once*, any subsequent calls to `readlines` after the first one will therefore give you an empty list.

Demo:

```
>>> with open('testfile.txt') as f:
...     a = f.readlines()
...     b = f.readlines()
...     a
...     b
... 
['hello\n', 'stack\n', 'overflow\n']
[]
```