# Resetting an iterator, which is a map object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm learning Python by myself.

I've come across the following

```
sol=map(pow,[1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

`sol` is an iterator.

When I run consecutively `next(sol)`, I will iterate along the elements of `sol`, until I get `StopIteration` error.

However, how can I restart the iteration?

I've tried `iter_1=itertools.cycle(sol)`, but I need to restart `sol` by running `sol=map(pow,[1,2,3],[4,5,6])` and only then `iter_1=itertools.cycle(sol)`.

Is there another way?

Comment: Do you really want to repeat the iterator indefinitely ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can iterators be reset in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266180/can-iterators-be-reset-in-python)

Comment: @yatu It's more of a theoretical question. In practice, I don't.

Comment: You can't, because the iterator (in general) doesn't remember the previous values its `__next__` method returned.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Thoses answers are for when the iterator is a file type, I think.  Then, I would use seek method. I'm not sure how to use seek with a map object...

Comment: `itertools.cycle` is indeed the answer. Try this `c = cycle(map(pow,[1,2,3],[4,5,6]))`. And then you will have the effect you desire iterating over `c`.

Comment: @accdias That doesn't really reset the iterator. Given `c`, you have no way of knowing where the "dividing point" between the end of the original iterator and its beginning is, and you can't reset to the beginning from an arbitrary position in the iterator. (But I'm thinking of the broader definition of "reset".)

Comment: @chepner, Indeed. But it will give the result expected on the OP, don't you agree?

Comment: @accdias Do I need import some extra module? because when I run your command, I get 
NameError: name 'cycle' is not defined

Comment: @accdias Depends on the use case; does it matter that you can no longer distinguish between which "phase" of the iteration you are on? Sometimes, you might need (or at least want) to know when you've reached the end of the original iterator and are going back to the beginning; other times, you don't. You also might only want to repeat *once*, not indefinitely. `next(c)` will never raise `StopIteration` or give any indication of when you are at the point where `next(sol)` would have.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, I'm using Python 3.7.6 here. `itertools` is in the standard library and all I do is `from itertools import cycle` or, if you want to preserve the namespace, `import itertools`.

Comment: @chepner, I agree. But judging what is described by the OP, it seems it doesn't matter since he just consecutively runs `next(sol)`. So I'm guessing `cycle` works for him in that case.

Comment: If you need to cache the "elements" of an iterator you obviously just use `list(it)`. `itertools.cycle` is just sugar to do that for you.

Comment: @accdias well it's strange. If I do 'from itertools import cycle' it works. However, if I just do 'import itertools', my jupyter notebook doesn't recognise cycle()

Comment: You'd need to call `itertools.cycle` if you just `import itertools`, since you just import the module, but the functions in it remain in the (now imported) namespace of `itertools`.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, that's right. If you do `import itertools` you are preserving the namespace and then you must call `itertools.cycle()` instead.

Comment: Many thanks everyone! Kind regards ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating an iterator/generator consumes the values from it (infinite generators being an exception), meaning that they will no longer be available on future iterations (as you've seen). For a typical iterator/generator in Python, the only true way to "restart" it is to re-initialize it.

```
>>> sol = map(pow, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])      
>>> list(sol)
[1, 32, 729]
>>> next(sol)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> sol = map(pow, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
>>> next(sol)
1
```

There are ways that you can work with the iterator to make it reusable though, such as with `itertools.tee` (as mentioned by one of the answers to the question linked by @JanChristophTerasa), or to convert the iterator into a list, which will persist its data.

[`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> sol = map(pow, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
>>> a, b = tee(sol, 2)  
>>> list(a)
[1, 32, 729]
>>> list(b)
[1, 32, 729]
>>> list(a)
[]
```

with `tee` though, both `a` and `b` will still be iterators, so you'll have the same problem with them.

Another common way to handle this is with `list()`

```
sol = list(map(pow, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
>>> sol
[1, 32, 729]
>>> sol
[1, 32, 729]
```

Now, `sol` is a list of values instead of an iterator, which means you can iterate it as many times as you want - the values will remain there. This *does* mean you can't use `next` with it (in the sense of `next(sol)`), but you can get an iterator back from your new list with `iter(sol)` if you need an iterator specifically.

**Edit**

I saw `itertools.cycle` mentioned in the comments, which is also a valid option so I thought I might add some info on it here as well.

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is one of those infinite generators I mentioned at the start. It *is still an iterator*, but in a way that you'll never run out of values.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> sol = map(pow, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
>>> infinite = cycle(sol)
>>> for _ in range(5):                        
...     print(next(infinite))
... 
1
32
729
1
32
>>>
```

A few notes on this - after iterating `infinite` N times, it will be positioned after whatever the last value was pulled from it. Iterating it again later *will resume* from that position, *not* from the start.

Also, and this is very important, *do not* iterate an infinite generator in an unbounded fashion, like `list(infinite)` or `for x in infinite:`, or you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: I think `itertools.cycle` is a more appropriate answer to this than `itertools.tee`. With `tee` you need to know how many times you want to iterate beforehand (or tee again every time), with `cycle` you can just reuse the iterator as you please.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa a good point, I added `cycle` to the post

Comment: @b_c, if you are following the comments and the answers, you will see I've already suggested that.

Comment: @accidias Your answer went up while I was editing. I included a bit more info to consider when using an infinite generator that I thought would be helpful, but I did give you an upvote for the useful answer.

Comment: No worries. It was just a heads up call.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the effect you described on the OP, you can use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Something like this:

```py
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan 30 2020, 09:44:41) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> c = cycle(map(pow,[1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
32
>>> next(c)
729
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
32
>>>
```

But take into consideration the comments on the OP before you choose this approach.