# Ternary tree paths

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, functional-programming, ternary-tree

I'm solving the following question:

> Given a ternary tree (each node of the tree has at most three
> children), find all root-to-leaf paths.

**Example:**

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import itertools
from collections import deque, Iterable


class TernaryNode:
    def __init__(self, val: int) -> None:
        self.children: list[TernaryNode] = []
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.val)


def ternary_tree_paths(root: TernaryNode) -> Iterable[Iterable[int]]:
    def _visit(node: TernaryNode) -> Iterable[deque[int]]:
        if not node:
            return []
        if not node.children:
            queue = deque()
            queue.append(node.val)
            return [queue]
        # **
        paths = itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda ch: _visit(ch), node.children))
        for p in paths:
            p.appendleft(node.val)

        return paths

    return _visit(root)
```

As shown, **the code above returns an empty list**, where as the desired behavior is `[deque([1, 2, 3]), deque([1, 4]), deque([1, 6])]`. Note the line with **; if I rewrite that line as `paths = [p for ch in node.children for p in _visit(ch)]`, it works as expected. I'm guessing the problem is because function `from_iterable` is evaluated lazily, but shouldn't it be forced to evaluate when I'm iterating over the items?

Comment: Would be nice to provide a [mre]...

Comment: @Julien You're looking at it.

Comment: There is no actual tree defined in your code. Does the code above exhibit your error? No it doesn't. So it's not a [mre].

Comment: All I said is that it would be nice to provide an example that can be copied and pasted, rather than expecting people to to code that by themselves from a picture. You are of course not obliged to as nice as people who still try to help you. Have a good day :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: calling 'list' on a map object twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486950/python-calling-list-on-a-map-object-twice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting an iterator, which is a map object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304880/resetting-an-iterator-which-is-a-map-object)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've converted the `**` to a aid with copy-pasting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If you can make up your mind which of the answers is actually relevant to my question, perhaps I can read it and see if it helps. Pasting several links that you think is pertinent is not exactly helpful.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar All of them. If I had to pick, the third fits the issue best, whereas the first two fit the use-case best. Depends on how much abstraction you want in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exhausting the chain iterable when trying to do the `appendleft` to each of the items. After that `paths` is empty.

You need to make sure the iterable is evaluated only once:

```
def ternary_tree_paths(root: TernaryNode) -> Iterable[Iterable[int]]:
    def _visit(node: TernaryNode) -> Iterable[deque[int]]:
        if not node:
            return []
        if not node.children:
            queue = deque()
            queue.append(node.val)
            return [queue]
        paths = itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(_visit, node.children))
        retval = [] # to keep track of results
        for p in paths: # iterate
            p.appendleft(node.val)
            retval.append(p) # add to result

        return retval # return result

    return _visit(root)
```

This yields:

```
[deque([1, 2, 3]), deque([1, 4]), deque([1, 6])]
```

For the example in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like using a list solves this issue without needing an additional list `retval`.