# Why a print modifies a pairwise?

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

data={
    'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'Y': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1,2,3,4,5,5],
    'Cat':["cat","dog",None,None,"dog","dog",None,None,"cat","dog"  ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x_pairs = it.pairwise(df['X'])
y_pairs = it.pairwise(df['Y'])

# print(list(x_pairs))  #<--Uncomment this
# print(list(y_pairs))

for x, y in zip(x_pairs, y_pairs):
  print("x",x,"y",y)
```

This code works. It shows me the x and y pairs.

Why when I uncomment the print statement the loop does not work anymore?

Comment: iterators can only be consumed once.

Comment: so the print (or the list??) consume the iterator? mmm interesting

Comment: The `list`, obviously. How else do you expect `list` to get the values from the iterator?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3266180/3196753

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good to know. Thanks for teaching it.

Comment: @KansaiRobot keep in mind that an iterator is not the same as an iterable. A list is an example of an iterable, something you can iterate over (many times) and that actually holds the data. An iterator is just a special object that allows you to iterate over something in a special way, pair-wise in this case. But once it completes, it's exhausted.